# What is wrong with this sentence: "This is an obstacle to start in Turkey"

Tags: grammar, gerunds, infinitives, ing

"This is an obstacle to start in Turkey."

This sentence is about making a business in Turkey and problems you can have. My friend said this sentence is more natural as "This is an obstacle to getting started in Turkey," but it is not clear to me why -ing is needed here. The -ing here is a gerund, right? I have a lot of problems knowing when it is OK to use gerunds or to-infinitives in sentences like this.

Comment: Is *"This is an obstacle to start in Turkey."* a headline in a newspaper or magazine?

Comment: No it is my sentence, not from a newspaper

Comment: I understand your problem knowing when to use the _-ing_ form or the _infinitive_ after nouns such as _obstacle_. There is no reason, for example, why it is _an obstacle to starting_, (https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/obstacle) but _an obligation to start_ (https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/obligation). You simply have to look them up case-by-case.

Comment: 'This is an obstacle to a start in Turkey' correctly has what some analyse as a determiner phrase as part of the PP complement of 'obstacle'. With 'This is an obstacle to starting in Turkey', use of 'a' before the (nominal-orientated; 'nouny') ing-form would be rare (and very formal), though not as rare as the plural form _startings_.

Comment: @Shoe Different constructions: _An obstacle to what? // An obligation to **do** what?_

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. My _obligation_ example was maybe a red herring. I was just making the point that there is no 'rule' that would allow the OP to know whether it should be _An obstacle to __do__ what?_ or _An obstacle to __doing__ what?_

Comment: The problem is that "An obstacle to start in Turkey" makes the obstacle sound as though it is the thing to start rather than being something which makes it difficult to start a business in Turkey. It has the same form as "an oven to install in the kitchen", "a book to read in bed" or "a job to start in the morning". In each case the noun (oven, book, job) is, in a sense, the object of the verb (to install, to read, to start) and in your sentence "obstacle" has the same relationship to "to start".

Answer (score 2):

If you say

> This is an obstacle ***to start*** in Turkey.

"to start" looks like an [infinitive of purpose](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/infinitives-of-purpose.html), but this is contrary to the meaning of the sentence. "This" prevents something from happening, it does not make it happen. ***Obstacle to starting*** is correct, because "to" is a preposition (it is not part of a to-infinitive). Prepositions are followed by nouns, and in this case the gerund "starting" functions as a noun. We are asking the question: "This is an obstacle to what?", not "What kind of obstacle is this?" and even less "What purpose does this obstacle have?" The answer of "To what?" is "To starting in Turkey", where "starting" can be replaced by nouns like ***commencement*** or ***debut*** (these are just examples, I am not saying they are perfect synonyms):

> This is an obstacle ***to starting*** in Turkey. This is an obstacle ***to our debut*** in Turkey.

"an obstacle" can be replaced by a verb like "prevent":

> This prevents our debut in Turkey. This prevents us from starting in Turkey.

As for "obligation to do something" that was discussed in the comments, this is an idiomatic phrase:

> have a duty​/​responsibility​/​obligation etc (to do something) which is used for saying ***you must do*** something ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillanthesaurus.com/have-a-duty-responsibility-obligation-etc-to-do-something))

For example:

> Buyers have no legal ***obligation to disclose*** personal financial information.

Here you would ask the question, "Which obligation?"

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obligation) shows that "obligation" is followed by a to infinitive:

> [ + to infinitive ]
>
> - If you have not signed a contract, you are under
>   no obligation to (= it is not necessary to) pay them any money.
> - You
>   have a legal obligation to (= the law says you must) ensure your child
>   receives an education.

"Obligation" can be followed by the preposition TO, but TO needs to be followed by a noun (phrase):

> One has an obligation ***to one's friends***. (*To whom? To one's friends.)*

Having said all that, I also checked [Gngram 1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=obstacle+to+do%2Cobstacle+to+doing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cobstacle%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobstacle%20to%20doing%3B%2Cc0) and [Gngram 2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=obligation%20to%20do%2Cobligation%20to%20doing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cobligation%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobligation%20to%20doing%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cobligation%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobligation%20to%20doing%3B%2Cc0), and I was surprised to see that it found instances of "obstacle to do" and "obligation to doing", even if they are very rare. However, if you use ***obstacle + to + Gerund*** and ***obligation + to infinitive***, you will always be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the sentence is nothing syntactical. It is, rather, fatally unclear. We don't know what the demonstrative pronoun "this" refers to, so we're in the dark about the subject of the sentence, which appears to be part of a conversation.

"To start in Turkey" is equally murky. Starting what? Is the nature of the obstacle physical, political, economic, or something else? "I'd start in general poultry if I were you. To start in turkey is an obstacle--too small a market, too small a margin."

In short, we have no idea what the sentence means and no way of finding out with the information given.

Answer (score 0):

*An obstacle* requires *to* with a gerund, not an infinitive. There is no reason for this: it just happens to be a fact about English at the moment. (It might have changed  fifty years from now).

As another answer says, if you say *an obstacle to start ..*, the *to start* cannot be read as a complement of *obstacle*, and must be interpreted in a different way.

> an obstacle to starting in Turkey

is fine as a noun phrase.

Comment: 'This is an encouragement to start in Turkey' / 'This is an encouragement for us to start in Turkey' are, perversely, idiomatic. But 'We were encouraged to _start ..._' exists. ''Be an obstacle to' seems pretty cohesive, requiring something more nouny.